# PostgreSQL complex JOIN or Subselect query structure

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the following table structure in Postgres:

```
     Column      |          Type          
-----------------+------------------------
 alternatenameid | integer                
 geonameid       | integer                
 isolanguage     | character varying(7)   
 alternatename   | character varying(300) 
 ispreferredname | boolean                
 isshortname     | boolean
```

For simplicity let's say we have the following data:

```
 alternatenameid | geonameid | isolanguage |    alternatename      | ispreferredname | isshortname
-----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------
 2421691         |   1835841 | es          | Corea, República de   | t               |            
 1562679         |   1835841 | es          | Corea del Sur         |                 | t          
 1562677         |   1835841 | en          | South Korea           |                 | t          
 8103216         |   1835841 | en          | Korea, Republic of    |                 |
```

The table stores translation strings of toponyms where each toponym, in this case the country South Korea, has a unique geonameid (1835841). Each toponym may have translations in different languages, defined by the isolanguage column, and these translated names can be either the preferred name (boolean ispreferredname), the short name (boolean isshortname), or just neither (both fields NULL). I am having trouble creating a new table from this data with this structure:

```
     Column      |          Type          
-----------------+------------------------
 id              | integer                
 geonameid       | integer                
 isolanguage     | character varying(7)   
 alternatename   | character varying(300) 
 preferredname   | character varying(300) 
 shortname       | character varying(300)
```

And the following data:

```
id     | geonameid | isolanguage |    alternatename      |    preferredname    | shortname
-------+-----------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------
 (int) |   1835841 | es          |                       | Corea, República de | Corea del Sur
 (int) |   1835841 | en          | Korea, Republic of    |                     | South Korea
```

Where the core structure is based on (DISTINCT geonameid, isolanguage) and preferredname and shortname contain the strings of the ispreferredname and isshortname rows and alternatename contains the corresponding string if ispreferredname and isshortname are not present. I am not versed in complex JOIN or Sub-SELECT clauses and I will appreciate your help.

### Solution:

Like Gordon pointed out, this can be accomplished with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT geonameid, isolanguage,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ispreferredname IS TRUE OR isshortname IS TRUE THEN NULL
                ELSE alternatename
           END) AS alternatename,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ispreferredname IS TRUE THEN alternatename
           END) AS preferredname,
       MAX(CASE WHEN isshortname IS TRUE THEN alternatename
           END) AS shortname
FROM table t
GROUP BY geonameid, isolanguage;
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select geonameid, isolanguage,
       max(case when ispreferredname = t or isshortname = t then NULL
                else alternatename
           end) as alternatename,
       max(case when ispreferredname = t then alternatename
           end) as preferredname,
       max(case when isshortname = t then alternatename
           end) as shortname
from table t
group by geonameid, isolanguage;
```

The first condition is a bit tricky, because I do not know what values the flags take on when they are not `t`.  This should work if they are spaces, empty strings, or `NULL`s.

Comment: The ispreferredname and isshortname are Boolean fields and when the value is TRUE psql displays it as a t. I just had to change the = t comparison to IS TRUE to make it work. Many thanks, Gordon!